# ORACLE - How to create temporary field based on specific data in specific field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an ORACLE View and have to generate a report based on this View. This is the View example.

```
SELECT DATE, VOUCHER_NO, CURRENCY, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, JOURNAL_TYPE, COA_NO 
FROM VIEW_EXAMPLE

|DATE      |VOUCHER_NO|CURRENCY|AMOUNT|DESCRIPTION|JOURNAL_TYPE|COA_NO|

|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150001|
|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |(NULL)|
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1500  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150002|
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |530001|
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |540002|
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |4000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150003|
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520002|
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520004|
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520005|
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520010|
```

I have to get the records by `DATE` and `COA_NO` as the parameter, but as you can see, the `COA_NO` where `JOURNAL_TYPE` is `DEBIT` are different. The `COA_NO` that match the parameter is in the `CREDIT`. The data is about credit and debit pairs based on the `VOUCHER_NO` and one credit can have more than one debit.

At first, I use this query:

```
SELECT DATE, VOUCHER_NO, CURRENCY, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, JOURNAL_TYPE, COA_NO
FROM VIEW_EXAMPLE
WHERE DATE = @date
AND VOUCHER_NO IN (SELECT VOUCHER_NO FROM VIEW_EXAMPLE WHERE COA_NO = @coa_no)
```

It works if I just want to get one `COA_NO`. But, the problem is I also have to get all the `COA_NO` in specific `DATE` and use it to group the data (in C#).

I also try to create two queries, first to get all `COA_NO` in a specific date, and second query the data by looping it using foreach `COA_NO` in that date. But, it is very slow, because it had to query to database every `COA_NO` in that date.

So I think I have to create a temporary field which contains the `COA_NO` of credit to all the records, like this.

```
|DATE      |VOUCHER_NO|CURRENCY|AMOUNT|DESCRIPTION|JOURNAL_TYPE|COA_NO|TEMP_FIELD|

|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150001|150001    |
|03/30/2016|0000000001|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |(NULL)|150001    |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1500  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150002|150002    |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |530001|150002    |
|03/30/2016|0000000002|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |540002|150002    |
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |4000  |ABCD       |CREDIT      |150003|150003    |
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |2000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520002|150003    |
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |1000  |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520004|150003    |
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520005|150003    |
|03/31/2016|0000000003|USD     |500   |ABCD       |DEBIT       |520010|150003    |
```

How to do this? Or is that another way to group this data by the `COA_NO`?

And also, I have to `ORDER` this data by `AMOUNT` without breaking the `VOUCHER_NO` pairs. (optional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an analytic function to determine the calculated column, something like:

```
with view_example as (select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'CREDIT' journal_type, 150001 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, null coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'CREDIT' journal_type, 150002 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 530001 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('30/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 540002 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 4000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'CREDIT' journal_type, 150003 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 2000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 520002 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 1000 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 520004 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 520005 coa_no from dual union all
                      select to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 voucher_no, 'USD' currency, 500 amount, 'ABCD' description, 'DEBIT' journal_type, 520010 coa_no from dual)
-- the above subquery is used to mimic the data in your VIEW_EXAMPLE.
-- You wouldn't need it - just use the SQL below:
select dt,
       voucher_no,
       currency,
       amount,
       description,
       journal_type,
       coa_no,
       max(case when journal_type = 'CREDIT' then coa_no end) over (partition by voucher_no) related_credit_coa_no
from   view_example
order by voucher_no, journal_type, amount;

DT         VOUCHER_NO CURRENCY     AMOUNT DESCRIPTION JOURNAL_TYPE     COA_NO RELATED_CREDIT_COA_NO
---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------- ---------------------
30/03/2016          1 USD            2000 ABCD        CREDIT           150001                150001
30/03/2016          1 USD            2000 ABCD        DEBIT                                  150001
30/03/2016          2 USD            1500 ABCD        CREDIT           150002                150002
30/03/2016          2 USD             500 ABCD        DEBIT            540002                150002
30/03/2016          2 USD            1000 ABCD        DEBIT            530001                150002
31/03/2016          3 USD            4000 ABCD        CREDIT           150003                150003
31/03/2016          3 USD             500 ABCD        DEBIT            520010                150003
31/03/2016          3 USD             500 ABCD        DEBIT            520005                150003
31/03/2016          3 USD            1000 ABCD        DEBIT            520004                150003
```

N.B. if debits could have a different date to their credits, then you could end up getting incorrect results if you add a filter on the date directly on the above query - instead, you'd have to use a subquery, eg.

```
select *
from   (select dt,
               voucher_no,
               currency,
               amount,
               description,
               journal_type,
               coa_no,
               max(case when journal_type = 'CREDIT' then coa_no end) over (partition by voucher_no) related_credit_coa_no
        from   view_example)
where dt = :p_date
-- and related_credit_coa_no = :p_coa_no  -- if required
order by voucher_no, journal_type, amount;
```

Comment: Many thanks Boneist, it really worked. I can generate the report faster now.